# How to load application properties from a database via Spring framework (v4.0.3)

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to figure out how to load all my application properties from a database table via Spring (4.0.3).  right now my application has a set of property files (approx a dozen or so). these property files are duplicated (not the values) for each environment.  take below:

config.jar

- dev

  - inErrorCodes.properties
  - outErrCodes.properties
  - report.properties
  - email.properties
- test

  - inErrorCodes.properties
  - outErrCodes.properties
  - report.properties
  - email.properties
- prod

  - inErrorCodes.properties
  - outErrCodes.properties
  - report.properties
  - email.properties

and here is a snippet from xml config:

```
<util:properties id="inboundErrorCodes"                 
   location="classpath:config/${spring.profiles.active}/inErrCodes.properties"/>
<util:properties id="outboundErrorCodes"                 
   location="classpath:config/${spring.profiles.active}/outErrCodes.properties"/>
<util:properties id="reportProperties"                 
   location="classpath:config/${spring.profiles.active}/report.properties"/>
<util:properties id="emailProperties"                 
   location="classpath:config/${spring.profiles.active}/email.properties"/>
```

and then the usage in a source file:

```
...
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("testService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {  

    private Properties inboundErrorCodes = null;
    private Properties outboundErrorCodes = null;
    private Properties reportProperties = null;
    private Properties emailProperties = null;

    @Inject
    public TestServiceImpl(@Named("inboundErrorCodes") final Properties inboundErrorCodes,
                           @Named("outboundErrorCodes") final Properties outboundErrorCodes,
                           @Named("reportProperties") final Properties reportProperties,
                           @Named("emailProperties") final Properties emailProperties ) {
```

a couple other caveats. some of the properties in the errorCodes files have the same key.  for example

```
inErrorCodes.properties
    error.code.1001=bad file name.

outErrCodes.properties
    error.code.1001=bad header info.
```

ideally, all keys would be unique across all files, but this is a legacy app.  so what I was hoping to accomplish was to have a database table (jndi from all envs except local, where it would just be a datasource).  the table might look like (table name=APP_PROPERTIES)

```
id          key              value           category
==    ===============    =============     ============
 1    error.code.1001    bad file name.    inErrorCodes
 2    error.code.1001    bad header info.  outErrorCodes
 3    default.subject    Successful order     email
 4    sales.title        NE Sales Region     report
```

A couple other things.  I would prefer to use annotations over xml config.  And I would like to find a way to make the properties reloadable.  if one of the values was updated in the database, it would be great if I could call a Spring function to reload, or maybe even some pooling mechanism.  this is, of course, in lieu of restarting the application.  also, the ${spring.profiles.active} noted above is a JVM variable (set in application server console) that must be set in every environment.  any pointers would be really appreciated.  I searched quite a bit on the Spring @PropertySource, but couldn't find anything really related to what I was trying.

thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you, it not for 4.0.3 but it works.

http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

Comment: thank you very much for pointing me to this resource.  it definitely helps me get a better understanding of how to both wire up property files and properties from a database table.  I was hoping to do most of the spring configuration via annotations.  any ideas related to the PropertySource Spring annotation?  thank you again for your help.