# Load spring boot app properties from database

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I need you to advice me with this issue, in a spring boot application I load some properties from database like (cron periods, email data), I need to export these properties in the application context in order to spring build the corresponding beans with the loaded data. How could I do this?

Comment: How about the following link;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465360/spring-boot-use-database-and-application-properties-for-configuration

Comment: I tried that example already, but it only works on the second restart. Now, I read about the comment "Those properties from database can be used to configure Beans. Although I'd prefer to init them not in @PostConstruct but in custom BeanPostProcessor just after DataSource has been initiated ", could you address me about how to do this?

Comment: do you want to gran values from database for `@Value` property injection or you just want a bean composed of those properties from the db?

Comment: Hi Phani thanks for replying, I need the first option, but I already found a solution, I'll post it right away.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For those who need load properties from database before application starts, and make those props accesible by @Value anywhere in your project, just add this processor.

```
public class ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
/**
 * Name of the custom property source added by this post processor class
 */
private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "databaseProperties";

private String[] KEYS = {
        "excel.threads",
        "cronDelay",
        "cronDelayEmail",
        "spring.mail.username",
        "spring.mail.password",
        "spring.mail.host",
        "spring.mail.port",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enabled",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.debug",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.port",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.class",
        "spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.fallback",
        "white.executor.threads",
        "white.search.threads",
        "lot.sync.threads",
        "lot.async.threads",
        "lot.soap.threads",
        "excel.async.threads",
        "kpi.threads",
        "upload.threads"
};

/**
 * Adds Spring Environment custom logic. This custom logic fetch properties from database and setting highest precedence
 */
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {

    Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();

    try {

        // Build manually datasource to ServiceConfig
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                .password(environment.getProperty("spring.mail.password"))
                .url(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .build();

        // Fetch all properties

        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();

        JTrace.genLog(LogSeverity.informational, "cargando configuracion de la base de datos");

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT value FROM config WHERE id = ?");

        for (int i = 0; i < KEYS.length; i++) {

            String key = KEYS[i];

            preparedStatement.setString(1, key);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Populate all properties into the property source
            while (rs.next()) {
                propertySource.put(key, rs.getString("value"));
            }

            rs.close();
            preparedStatement.clearParameters();

        }

        preparedStatement.close();
        connection.close();

        // Create a custom property source with the highest precedence and add it to Spring Environment
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, propertySource));

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
} // class ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor end
```

In **application.properties** must exist datasource data in order to be able to connect to database.

Then in folder **META-INF** create a file named **spring.factories** an there put the following line:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=test.config.ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor
```

And that's it, retreived properties will be accessible anywhere.

Comment: This would work if i wanted to read values from database like a username for my email service right?

Comment: Exacttly, its for loading configuration data from database.

Comment: A bit of a follow-up on this. Will it also take updated properties from DB at runtime or is it loaded once at startup only? What I mean is let's say at application startup there was some property in DB as x=y (key is x and corresponding value is y). At some point after application has started I change the value for x to be z. Will that new value reflect in the running application or would it need a restart only?

Comment: Be aware that this method opens up a 2nd HikariCP. So if you have strong database connection limitations this might be a problem for you, as all the connections (settings picked up via injection) will be idle and stay there forever if not configured otherwise.

Comment: Instead of `DataSourceBuilder.create()` you want to use: `new SingleConnectionDataSource();` and later call `ds.destroy()` to get rid of "idle connections"

Answer (score 9):

I think it’s a good idea to use BeanPostProcessor and Binder so that you don’t need to list all the attributes you want to read.
The following code refers to ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.

```java
public class PropertiesInsideDatabaseInitializer implements BeanPostProcessor, InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private BeanDefinitionRegistry registry;
    private Map<String, Object> systemConfigMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final String propertySourceName = "propertiesInsideDatabase";

    public PropertiesInsideDatabaseInitializer(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.get(this.applicationContext, bean, beanName));
        return bean;
    }

    private void bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBean propertiesBean) {
        if (propertiesBean == null || hasBoundValueObject(propertiesBean.getName())) {
            return;
        }
        Assert.state(propertiesBean.getBindMethod() == ConfigurationPropertiesBean.BindMethod.JAVA_BEAN, "Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties for bean '"
                + propertiesBean.getName() + "'. Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean");
        try {
            Bindable<?> target = propertiesBean.asBindTarget();
            ConfigurationProperties annotation = propertiesBean.getAnnotation();
            BindHandler bindHandler = new IgnoreTopLevelConverterNotFoundBindHandler();
            MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
            mutablePropertySources.addLast(new MapPropertySource(propertySourceName, systemConfigMap));
            Binder binder = new Binder(ConfigurationPropertySources.from(mutablePropertySources), new PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver(mutablePropertySources),
                    ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance(), getPropertyEditorInitializer(), null);
            binder.bind(annotation.prefix(), target, bindHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("", ex);
        }
    }

    private Consumer<PropertyEditorRegistry> getPropertyEditorInitializer() {
        if (this.applicationContext instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
            return ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) this.applicationContext).getBeanFactory()::copyRegisteredEditorsTo;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean hasBoundValueObject(String beanName) {
        return this.registry.containsBeanDefinition(beanName) && this.registry
                .getBeanDefinition(beanName).getClass().getName().contains("ConfigurationPropertiesValueObjectBeanDefinition");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        String sql = "SELECT key, value from system_config";
        List<Map<String, Object>> maps = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        for (Map<String, Object> map : maps) {
            String key = String.valueOf(map.get("key"));
            Object value = map.get("value");
            systemConfigMap.put(key, value);
        }
        this.registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Modifying the PropertySources in Environment can also be achieved. The BeanPostProcessor interface is implemented to initialize it before creating the Bean

```java
public class PropertiesInsideDatabaseInitializer implements BeanPostProcessor, InitializingBean, EnvironmentAware {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    private final String propertySourceName = "propertiesInsideDatabase";


    public PropertiesInsideDatabaseInitializer(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if(environment != null){
            Map<String, Object> systemConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
            String sql = "SELECT key, value from system_config";
            List<Map<String, Object>> maps = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
            for (Map<String, Object> map : maps) {
                String key = String.valueOf(map.get("key"));
                Object value = map.get("value");
                systemConfigMap.put(key, value);
            }
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(propertySourceName, systemConfigMap));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        if(environment instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment){
            this.environment = (ConfigurableEnvironment) environment;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could configure the beans with the database values manually depending on what your need is (this way you can take advantage of Spring CDI and boot database configs).

Take setting the session timeout for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionListener httpSessionListener(){
        return new MyHttpSessionListener();
    }
}
```

Then a bean definition for configuring the bean:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {   
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        se.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(this.myRepository.getSessionTimeoutSeconds()); 
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // Noop
    }

}
```

Note: you could move the database call to a `@PostConstruct` method to avoid making it for each session.

Answer (score 2):

Using the DatabaseConfiguration class from org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.8.0 dependency makes the life much easier. In conjunction with spring boot 2.7.3 (rsp. spring 5.3.22) following setup worked for me.

Precondition: a bean of type DataSource must have been configured elsewhere.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.configuration2.ConfigurationConverter;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;

@Configuration
public class ConfigFromDb implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext( ApplicationContext aApplicationContext )
    {
        var dbConfig = aApplicationContext.getBean(DatabaseConfiguration.class);
        var props = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(dbConfig);
        var propSource = new PropertiesPropertySource("CONFIGURATION_FROM_DB", props);
        var env = (ConfigurableEnvironment) aApplicationContext.getEnvironment();
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(propSource);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onAppStart(ContextRefreshedEvent aEvent)
    {
        var context = aEvent.getApplicationContext();
        var env = context.getEnvironment();
        System.out.println( "ConfigKeyFromDB: " + env.getProperty("ConfigKeyFromDB") );
    }

    @Bean
    public static DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration( DataSource aDataSource )
    {
        var result = new DatabaseConfiguration();
        result.setDataSource( aDataSource);
        result.setTable( "CONFIGURATION" );
        result.setKeyColumn( "CONFIG_KEY" );
        result.setValueColumn( "CONFIG_VALUE" );
        return result;
    }
}
```

The bean DatabaseConfiguration is able to load configuration values from the DB (whose access is configured in the param aDataSource).

The DB has a table named "CONFIGURATION". This table has a column named "CONFIG_KEY" and a column named "CONFIG_VALUE" (of course, the table and the columns may have any name of your choice).

The setApplicationContext method fetches above bean from the context, extracts the configured values as java Properties class, converts these to a PropertiesPropertySource which can be added to the environment.

The event listener onAppStart is just for proving that such a DB config value can be fetched from environment.

Note that adding the properties to spring's environment is not enough for resolving property placeholders (e.g. in @Value annotated members). To achieve this, you have to provide one more bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer dbConfigForVariableResolving(DatabaseConfiguration aDbConfig)
{
    var result = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    var props = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(aDbConfig);
    result.setProperties(props);
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the configuration values from the database to check for updates using a schedule for exemple?

Comment: Probably yes, but I didn't try. One possibility would be to setup a scheduler that looks up the configuration 'manually' and updates the spring environment (replace the existing CONFIGURATION_FROM_DB). Or you can try to define the dbConfigForVariableResolving bean as prototype scoped (along with another prototyped spring bean whose members are @Value annotated). Such a prototyped bean is instantiated at the time when it is really used.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addendum to @Maya's answer, when you use multiple profiles (dev, prd for example) in your spring boot application, you need to check if `environment.getActiveProfile().length > 0`. I don't know the reason why spring called my postprocessor twice, once with profiles, so my final code was something like this:

```java
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    if(environment.getActiveProfile().length == 0)
       return;
    

     // Remaining code ...
```