# How to initialize properties from code instead of from my application-dev.yml, application-prod.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

My springboot application has a few yml files(each for various profiles - dev, prod) to load configurations from. I am moving the configurations to the DB.

Sample configurations are like,

```
admin:
  id: user05
  firstname: Brian
  lastname: Leavy
  purl: http://plixes.com/seai/ji
```

I have the values read from the DB and have it locally. I am not sure how to inject these values in my program onto these values, like key-value, as,

```
admin.id:user05
admin.firstname: Brian
admin.lastname: Leavy
admin.purl: http://plixes.com/seai/ji
```

so that they are available to the application as it would normally be.
I would need them to be initialized very early since some of the values are springboot configurations, like say,

```
server:
  port: 5007
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

**EDIT1:**

I just found out after hours of searching, that you could do something like this,

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Lexon.class);
app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
                       .singletonMap("server.port", "5007"));
app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
                       .singletonMap("admin.id", "user05"));
```

This works, but does not look clean.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407230/load-spring-boot-app-properties-from-database

Answer (score 0):

There is **Spring Boot Configuration** library that can externalize the configuration to a database or a git repository.

With that, you add an data source and an SQL statement to retrieve the property values.

For example, on application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT KEY, VALUE from  MY_PROPERTIES where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and LABEL=?
```

Check this site for more details: https://www.devglan.com/spring-cloud/jdbc-backend-spring-cloud-config