# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnProperty not seeing property dynamically set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and an external library. The application imports the library. There is a @Configuration class in the library which is loaded conditionally based on the value of this property.
I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6

The relevant classes are shown below:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class LibraryTrueConfiguration {

    // Load the Beans

}
```

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
public class LibraryFalseConfiguration {
    // Load the Beans
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.lo.bu.custom.lib") // top level package of the lib
public class SharedLibConfiguration {

}
```

Application's main class:

```
@Import(SharedLibConfiguration .class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApp {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Dynamically setting properties in Application's below config, these properties set are not being reflected by library for loading relevant configuration.

If my application.yml has custom.enabled=false and I am setting custom.enabled=true here in below code - it's not getting reflected in configuration file library is loading. It is loading file for custom.enabled=false

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicPropsConfig {

  // Service which fetch dynamic properties from DB
  @Autowired
  DynamicPropsLoader dynamicPropsLoader;
  @Autowired
  CustomProperties customProperties;
  
  @DependsOn("dynamicPropsLoader")
  @Autowired
  void setDynamicPropertiesInEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    System.out.println("[Before]customProperties = " + customProperties);

      environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("custom",
          dynamicPropsLoader.getCustomPropertiesMap()));

    final HashMap<Object, Object> customPropertiesMap = dynamicPropsLoader
        .getCustomPropertiesMap().keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> m.put(v, environment.getProperty(v)), HashMap::putAll);
    System.out.println("[After]customPropertiesMap = " + customPropertiesMap);

  }

}
```

```
@Component
public class DynamicCustomPropsClr implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  Environment environment;
  @Autowired
  ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment;
  @Value("${custom.enabled:}")
  String customEnabled;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("environment.getProperty(\"custom.enabled\") = " + environment
        .getProperty("custom.enabled"));
    System.out.println(
        "configurableEnvironment.getProperty(\"custom.enabled\") = " + configurableEnvironment
            .getProperty("custom.enabled"));
    System.out.println("customenabled = " + customenabled);
  }
}

output
------
environment.getProperty("custom.enabled") = true
configurableEnvironment.getProperty("custom.enabled") = true
customEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me fix the issue. We need to use EnvironmentPostProcessor along with META-INF/spring.factories file mentioned
[Load spring boot app properties from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407230/load-spring-boot-app-properties-from-database)