# How to setup configurations manually in Spring boot instead of using application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a basic spring boot application

Inside my application.properties file, I have placed below configuration,

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

keystore.jks is placed inside src/main/resources

Is there any way to add these configurations inside the java program and load the keystore.jks to enable https ?

Thanks

Comment: You can put application.properties inside the resources dir of your JAR. Spring will pick it up. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files

Comment: you can pass it as a command-line argument also: Java -jar jarname.jar -Dserver.port=9091 -Dserver.ssl.enabled=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep properties outside for executable file, you can use [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/). It has security features also.

If you need a database storage you can apply something custom like: [Load spring boot app properties from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407230/load-spring-boot-app-properties-from-database)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a YAML file instead of the application.properties file. The SpringApplication class will automatically support YAML as an alternative to properties whenever you have the SnakeYAML library on your classpath. We can also use coomand line arguments to specify the environment properties.

You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more details.