# How to read spring property files at run time based on runtime Flag

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a single server for Multiple countries lets say [c1,c2,c3 countries have p1,p2,p3 property files], i want to load all of them at once and want fetched/read its values based on country flag(This country flag will be derived based on login user configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I'll say you should use Zookeeper or Spring Cloud config for this.

For a native spring solution you can refer to this answer: [Load spring boot app properties from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407230/load-spring-boot-app-properties-from-database)

However, using Spring cloud will make this easier.