# How to load properties in Spring boot from external API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

We have legacy API and separate config management that houses properties files. In standalone Java app we pass some command line arguments to this API to tell it which file to read e.g. env name etc. This API gives us a Properties map which we use to initialize our app. How can I get call this API inside postProcessEnvironment and pass it the command line arguments passed to this app. Something similar was answered to [read config from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407230/load-spring-boot-app-properties-from-database). But I'm struggling on how to get hold of all command line arguments passed inside postProcessEnvironment.

To elaborate better attaching the source code:

```
public class LegacyConfigReader implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "legacyResource";

@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    System.out.println("inside postProcessEnvironment");

    //PROBLEM: How to get hold of command line arguments here passed into the main method
    String[] args = new String[]{"-p", "customParam1=val1", "-p", "customParam2=val2", "-p", "configDir=/tmp/config"};

    Map<String, String> legacyConfigMap = LegacyConfigUtils.readConfig(args);

    Map<String, Object> propertyResource = legacyConfigMap.entrySet()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, propertyResource));
}
```

}

Comment: Even If someone can suggest an alternate way to inject properties using legacy API, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically, based on [Sushil's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75871075/592355), though little "ugly":

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EnvPostProcessApplication {

    static String[] ARGS; // 1. 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ARGS = args; // 2.
        SpringApplication.run(EnvPostProcessApplication.class, args);
    }

}
...
public class MyEnvPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
      System.out.println(
        "inside postProcessEnvironment, args: "
        + Arrays.toString(EnvPostProcessApplication.ARGS) // 3.
      );
      // do something important...
    }
}
```

(assuming "main class" is *visible* to "post-processor")

Since spring-boot:3 we can integrate main method also in tests:

```java
@SpringBootTest(useMainMethod = ...)
```

---

Regarding the overall scenario (I still have questions/doubts):
What is the reason to load these (legacy) props that prioritized and early?

Since as long there is no strong reason for `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, I would do just so:

```java
package com.example.envpostprocess;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EnvPostProcessApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EnvPostProcessApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean // since/when there is no reason for "post-processing", we can use "regular bean":
  InitializingBean myInit(
    ConfigurableEnvironment cEnv, /* with all dependencies ... */
    ApplicationArguments args /* ... we need */
  ) {
    return () -> { // original code with less variables..please re-view:
      cEnv.getPropertySources().addFirst(
        new MapPropertySource(
          "legacyResource",
          LegacyConfigUtils.readConfig(args.getSourceArgs())
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
        )
      );
    };
  }

  private static class LegacyConfigUtils { // just a mock, expects String[], returns Map

    private static Map<String, String> readConfig(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("args are: " + Arrays.toString(args));
      return Map.of("foo", "bar", "tic", "toc");
    }
  }
}
```

Then test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class EnvPostProcessApplicationTests {

    @Value("${foo}")
    String foo;

    @Value("${tic}")
    String tic;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(foo);
        assertNotNull(tic);
        System.err.println(foo + " " + tic);
    }
}
```

passes.

---

One Last problem remains in any case:

To pass `args` to tests...

Solution:

- for "static hack": just set `ARGS` in a test class body/`@BeforeAll` method (utilizing `useMainMethod` ;)
- for "init bean": mock(bean)/replace `ApplicationArguments` ;)

---

Docs used:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html (+ refs)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.application-arguments

Comment: I'm just wondering how can we pass ConfigurableEnvironment and ApplicationArguments in myInit(...) method you defined? Can we pass them in any method returning a bean definition?

Comment: Correct, we can "auto wire" `ConfigurableEnvironment and ApplicationArguments` (theoretically) in any bean (definition)... The advantage of `InitializingBean` is it's "early load" ...(in second solution,) alternatively we could  use `Commandline-/ApplicationRunner` (which get "the args" else-/anyhow) *beans*...but theoretically: any "bean"

Comment: And (key point) `InitializimgBean` is "early enough" (to populate (configurable) environment with new properties) for: `@Value("${someLegacyProp}")` (in other beans;)

Comment: But if you have (e.g.) application.properties: `my.foo=bar-${someLegacyProp}/baz` (i.e. need "legacy props" to resolve different props), this would be an argument for "Post-Processing"..

Comment: Just tried your second solution. It didn't work. It could not inject a property from legacy into a field I had defined in a bean using @Value annotation. If I use first Solution using static field, I was able to inject legacy config value.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps should help you to add spring in legacy application. Uing these steps, you will not require to make any change in start script -

1. In main() method, load all configs using LegacyConfigReader. I believe you already doing it.
2. Expose all properties as System.setProperties()
3. Create Spring ApplicationContext
4. Refresh application context with Spring Java Config

All properties loaded in step#1 will be used by all beans.